# Count total and subtotal of nodes in neo4j in same query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create an all in one statement in cypher to populate a data table. Two fields count the number of `Sample`: one shows the total number, and the other shows the number without the additional `:Ghost` label:

```
 MATCH (a:Person)-[:OWNER]->(b:Project)-[:PROJECT]->(c:Import)-[:IMPORT|:INPUT|:OUTPUT*]->(d:Sample)
WITH a,b,c,d,d AS e WHERE NOT d:Ghost
RETURN DISTINCT b.Name,(a.`First Name` + " " + a.`Last Name`),b.Description,b.Date,count(DISTINCT c),count(DISTINCT d),count(DISTINCT e)
```

The problem is `d` and `e` come up with the same value, when in reality `e` should be smaller than `d`. I suspect somehow `d` and `e` are pointing to the same address. I can solve the problem by `MATCH` querying the graph again, but obviously that is expensive and I'd prefer to do it only once. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` filters what's returned by `WITH`, and you only get non-`Ghost` nodes. Use `CASE` for conditional results instead:

```
WITH a, b, c, d,
     CASE
         WHEN d:Ghost THEN null
         ELSE d
     END AS e
```

You could also `collect` the distinct sample nodes for the result, then get the size of the original list and a filtered list (so it won't deduplicate twice):

```
WITH DISTINCT b.Name AS projectName,
     (a.`First Name` + " " + a.`Last Name`) AS fullName,
     b.Description AS projectDescription,
     b.Date AS projectDate,
     count(DISTINCT c) AS importCount,
     collect(DISTINCT d) AS samples
RETURN projectName, fullName, projectDescription, projectDate, importCount,
       size(samples) AS sampleCount,
       size([s IN samples WHERE NOT s:Ghost]) as nonGhostCount
```